# Photoshop scripting : how to align layer center to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I've been googling all day to find a way to align a layer to the canvas proceeded by scripting, but haven't found a solution so far. I ended up with the code below, but it cannot do the job. Could anyone help, please?

```
var baseFile = new File(openDialog()); //open base JPEG file
var workFile = new File(openDialog()); //open work JPEG file
var baseDoc = app.open(baseFile);
var workDoc = app.open(workFile);

workDoc.resizeImage(280,280);
workDoc.artLayers[0].duplicate(baseDoc, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
app.activeDocument = baseDoc;

var Hoffset = (baseDoc.width - workDoc.width) / 2;
var Voffset = (baseDoc.height - workDoc.height) / 2;
baseDoc.layers[1].position = Array(Hoffset, Voffset);
```

Comment: Not sure what is the question: I tried this code and seems doing what you're looking for. The image in `workDoc` is resized and centered in the `baseDoc`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I realized the code I posted works just fine. I omitted some of the parts to make the code look tidy, which now I think I shouldn't have done. I posted another one without any omitting. If you have time, please take a look at it and share your thoughts. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19618505/2837159

Comment: I replied to your other question, hope it helps!