# How to align Smart Object layer center to the canvas?

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I've been googling all day to find a way to align a layer which is converted to Smart Object center to the canvas proceeded by scripting, but haven't found a solution so far. I ended up with the code below, but it doesn't do the job. Could anyone help, please?

```
var baseFile = new File(openDialog()); //open base JPEG file
var workFile = new File(openDialog()); //open work JPEG file
var baseDoc = app.open(baseFile);
var workDoc = app.open(workFile);

createSO(workDoc.layers[0]);
workDoc.resizeImage(280,280);
workDoc.artLayers[0].duplicate(baseDoc, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
app.activeDocument = baseDoc;

var Hoffset = (baseDoc.width - workDoc.width) / 2;
var Voffset = (baseDoc.height - workDoc.height) / 2;
baseDoc.layers[1].position = Array(Hoffset, Voffset);

function createSO(){
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var idnewPlacedLayer = stringIDToTypeID( "newPlacedLayer" );
    executeAction( idnewPlacedLayer, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
    return doc.activeLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify a bit in this way:

```
var baseFile = new File(openDialog()); //open base JPEG file
var workFile = new File(openDialog()); //open work JPEG file
var baseDoc = app.open(baseFile);
var workDoc = app.open(workFile, undefined, true);

workDoc.resizeImage(280, 280);
var duplicated = workDoc.artLayers[0].duplicate(baseDoc, ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
var Hoffset = (baseDoc.width - workDoc.width) / 2;
var Voffset = (baseDoc.height - workDoc.height) / 2;

app.activeDocument = baseDoc;

duplicated.translate(Hoffset, Voffset);
```

The main point here is using `translate` method; however you can also avoid to create a  `createSO` function, using the 3rd argument of `app.open` (that is `asSmartObject`).